# Script to open multiple links in multiple tabs, and then click links in those tabs

Tags: automation

I have a bunch of links (200+) of pages on a wiki that are broken (why they are broken is a mystery to me, but is irrelevant to my question). The way to fix these links on the wiki is to  1. open the page 2. click the "edit" button and then finally, 3. click "save" in the text editor page.

What's the easiest way to do this? I've tried Automator in OS X which sounded really good on paper..

Comment: @TravisJ why would you edit a 2 year old post? - you need to be downvoted about 10k for that one!

Comment: @Sorceri http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203638/burninate-script